# Lubuntu 18.04.1 will not connect to WiFi

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I Installed Lubuntu 18.04.1 32 bit version on a Samsung netbook with Atom processor. During installation i did choose to connect to my home network through wifi. At first that worked well. After updating the software wifi connection got lost. I cannot reconnect it. When I choose my wifi network Lubuntu does not respond. It will not ask for the wifi key.
I can only use the netbook with a wired connection.

The netbook ran prior to this on Lubuntu 16.04.x With that version wifo connection worked flawlessly.

The same happened a few weeks ago when I updated a laptop from Ubuntu 16.04.x 64 bit to 18.04.1. 64 bit. That laptop will no longer connect to wifi either.

What did I do wrong?

Ben

Comment: Try [Wireless network troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en).